# Box plot with ggplot2 using data from read.table

Tags: r

I am plotting a box plot that shows the height of students. However I am unsure what I use as x and y. I have only measurments, so one should be height and the other one amount of students that have that height.

```
x=N, y=Height
```

My code:

```
# Library
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# 1. Read data (comma separated)
data = read.table(text = "184,180,183,184,184,160,173", 
               sep=",",stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings="unknown")

# 2. Print table
print(data)

# 3. Plot box plot
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Students") +
  ylab("Height") + 
  ggtitle("Height of students")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best plot to represent a vector of data is an histogram. However you could use the boxplot by create a dummy factor that group your observation. i.e.

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  mutate(type="student") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=type, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Students") +
  ylab("Height") + 
  ggtitle("Height of students")
```

if you want a histogram (I think much better for your situation), you don'ty need the dummy factor and you could do something like :

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("Students") +
  ylab("Height") + 
  ggtitle("Height of students")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and input. I need the box plot. I already have a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

To use a boxplot correctly, you have to have one categorical variable and one continuous. Put the categorical (e.g. make, female, etc.) on the x-axis and the continuous on the y-axis (height in your case).

Comment: cannot x be amount of students that have that height?

Comment: Typically, you would give `ggplot` the unaggregated data.